# How to dim background when using qmessagebox?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I want to set the background in dim mode, when a QMessagebox is popped up.

Currently, I have tried to use a simple QMesssagebox, but the background shows as normal display, when it pops up.

The image for 1st page is as follow
[image]

When `go to next slide` is pushed, it goes to next index as follow
[image]

When going back to 1st index, the back button is pushed which pops up the messagebox as follow
[image]

However, the mainwindow seems to have no effect on its focus.
Therefore, what would I need to do to make it dimmer than the focused messagebox.

How can I do this? Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("message.ui",self)
        self.notification = QMessageBox()
        
        self.ui.next_slide.clicked.connect(self.second_index)

        self.ui.go_back.clicked.connect(self.alert_msg)

        self.show()


    def home(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def second_index(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def alert_msg(self):
        self.notification.setWindowTitle("Exiting")
        self.notification.setText("Are you sure, you want to exit")
        self.notification.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
        self.notification.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        self.back = self.notification.exec_()

        if self.back == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.home()
        else:
            pass
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow=MainWindow()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: The background of what?

Comment: @musicamante, Sorry for no clarification before but now I have reedited the following question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom widget that is a direct child of the window that has to be "dimmed", ensure that it always has the same size as that window, and just paint it with the selected color:

```py
class Dimmer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        parent = parent.window()
        super().__init__(parent)
        parent.installEventFilter(self)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.adaptToParent()
        self.show()

    def adaptToParent(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.parent().rect())

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == event.Resize:
            self.adaptToParent()
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.fillRect(self.rect(), QColor(127, 127, 127, 127))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def alert_msg(self):
        dimmer = Dimmer(self)
        # ...
        self.back = self.notification.exec_()
        dimmer.close()
```

Note that, unless you plan to reuse the "dim widget", it *must* be destroyed either by calling `close()` as done above (see the `WA_DeleteOnClose` flag) or using `deleteLater()`. Hiding it will not be enough.

Comment: I see, yes I understand that, if I dont close it it will always cover my parent window. This solution did help me. Thanks !

Comment: @ZubairAdil No, the point is that if you don't need to use it again, and do not close it but just *hide* it, it will stay in memory, occupying memory resources.

Comment: ohh yeah it make sense as it would take time to render it again if needed

Comment: No, the time to create such a simple widget is negligible for any decent computer and for this usage. It's about possible waste of memory resources. It might not be that relevant for this specific case, but some programs are created to be kept alive on computers that might not be restarted for *months*. While a widget normally doesn't occupy a lot of memory, if you're not careful you could end up with hundreds of thousands of "forgotten" objects that needlessly occupy memory and eventually *do* affect performance. You either destroy it every time, or you just use one and make it persistent.

Comment: oh I get it, the unwanted data which will fill up the memory